# Defining node features on creation

Tags: design-patterns, javafx, mouseevent, actionlistener, nodes

I have some sort of `nodes` in JavaFX application. All of them have the same properties and abilities. They respond on clicking in different circumstances identically, are dragged identically etc. 
Therefore I want to give them all `listeners` and other features **on creation**. How can I do it? What would be the best way to realize it architecturally? Thanks.

Comment: Normally you would write a method that created the node and then just call it for each one you wanted to create. You haven't said much about the context - is there any reason you can't do it that way?

Comment: I think I can. More than that, it is a good way but I lacked experience to think about it. If I create a method that firstly creates my Node and then binds all necessary listeners to it - should I locate all such methods in the Node class or I have to take this logic away to another class?

Comment: It depends a bit. In the simplest case, where you only need the nodes to be created in a single class, then I would just create a private method in that class. If you need to create these in multiple places, you might consider writing a separate "factory class" that has the creation methods you need. Then just instantiate that class wherever you need it and call the methods. (You can extend this further to an abstract factory pattern of you need.) If you can be more specific about what you need (post some code) I can probably write an answer...

Comment: Thank you a lot, James! For now I think I should try to create answer by my own hands (except parts where I really stuck) but I'd like to share the whole app code for critique after it would be done.